# Parse the following XML using Retrofit SimpleXml-Converter with a POJO class

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, retrofit2

This is my xml structure

```
<downloads>
<item>98cfa929ee93149e245aabf5e4377058</item>
<item>498b513aa646d6ef1c407cbeabf6bd20</item>
<item>13815d2c0dd53a251bb53717b9f43b64</item>
<item>7a0615eb601264bbae0ad510a31fd61d</item>
<item>3157910f72705e60d0d4ba26c3fb0e84</item>
<item>29e037200d14e21b4ccdfbfaaf1621e8</item>
<item>5f5da6505eaa203d65d1a6203dd0e742</item>
<item>98dcbf2a73016cc9e72c3cbc101de151</item>
<item>7b21d3f11bf6b12e4c4abca7004ad80d</item>
<item>116049d5a4e53240b76666c6826fc6d6</item>
<item>c7ec466398f3d8cee56147c696760076</item>
<item>66ce3335de344b32986d2b77ff992ae2</item>
</downloads>
```

and the details xml

```
<download>
<item>
<key>9b94e79fecb1f055f279d95e800867f9</key>
<value>
A Jedi uses the Force for knowledge and defense, never for attack.
</value>
</item>
</download>
```

This is what I want to retrieve from the server and convert the above xml to it.

```
 public class DownloadPayloadCollection {
        // Class log identifier
        public final static String LOG_TAG = DownloadPayloadCollection.class.getSimpleName();
        @Root(name = "downloads")
        @ElementList(inline=true)
        private List<DownloadPayload> result;


        public DownloadPayloadCollection() {
        }

        public List<DownloadPayload> getResult() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "CALLED FROM getResult() " + result.toString());
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Here is the class that should represent the item elements.

```
@Root(name = "download")
public class DownloadPayload {

    @Element(name = "key", required = false)
    private String key;

    @Element(name = "value", required = false)
    private String value;

    public DownloadPayload() {
    }

    public String getKeyString() {
        return keyString;
    }

    public void setDownloadPayloadKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getDownloadPayloadKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I am confused on how to get an a list of the items elements. I can't seem to find a way to make the items a POJO, since it has no structure. How can I use RetrofitSimpleXmlConverter to achieve the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to read up a bit on how to use [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#scatter).

Your POJO deserialization classes are wrong, you want something like this:

```
@Root(name = "downloads")
public class Downloads {
    @ElementList(entry = "item", inline = true)
    private List<String> items;
}
```

Comment: Your answer worked! Its accepted.@Xyresic could you help me deserialize the DownloadPayload too, am stuck?

Comment: You need a another root Item class that holds the "key" and "value" string types. Your xml is DownloadPayload -> Item -> (key, value), not DownloadPayload -> (key, value) like you have in your question.